# App created with npx-create-next-app does not start properly after setup

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a next.js app and before I have added any code, just running npx create-next-app example-app, cd example-app and npm run dev returns the following error:

[image]

npx create-next-app was working perfectly fine on my machine yesterday and today it has only just started returning this error everytime I try to create a new app.

Are there any steps I can take to resolve this error?

package.json

[image]

[image]

index.tsx

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Inter } from '@next/font/google'
import styles from '@/styles/Home.module.css'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <div className={styles.description}>
          <p>
            Get started by editing&nbsp;
            <code className={styles.code}>pages/index.tsx</code>
          </p>
          <div>
            <a
              href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              By{' '}
              <Image
                src="/vercel.svg"
                alt="Vercel Logo"
                className={styles.vercelLogo}
                width={100}
                height={24}
                priority
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.center}>
          <Image
            className={styles.logo}
            src="/next.svg"
            alt="Next.js Logo"
            width={180}
            height={37}
            priority
          />
          <div className={styles.thirteen}>
            <Image
              src="/thirteen.svg"
              alt="13"
              width={40}
              height={31}
              priority
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.grid}>
          <a
            href="https://nextjs.org/docs?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            className={styles.card}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <h2 className={inter.className}>
              Docs <span>-&gt;</span>
            </h2>
            <p className={inter.className}>
              Find in-depth information about Next.js features and&nbsp;API.
            </p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://nextjs.org/learn?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            className={styles.card}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <h2 className={inter.className}>
              Learn <span>-&gt;</span>
            </h2>
            <p className={inter.className}>
              Learn about Next.js in an interactive course with&nbsp;quizzes!
            </p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://vercel.com/templates?framework=next.js&utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            className={styles.card}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <h2 className={inter.className}>
              Templates <span>-&gt;</span>
            </h2>
            <p className={inter.className}>
              Discover and deploy boilerplate example Next.js&nbsp;projects.
            </p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://vercel.com/new?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            className={styles.card}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <h2 className={inter.className}>
              Deploy <span>-&gt;</span>
            </h2>
            <p className={inter.className}>
              Instantly deploy your Next.js site to a shareable URL
              with&nbsp;Vercel.
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

_app.tsx

```
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

_document.tsx

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code where the error occurs. Also remember to not to use images for code/errors, just put the text here directly, with the proper formatting.

Comment: The point I tried to explain is that I literally added no code after starting the app with npx-create-next-app.... so there is  no code to show - it doesn't work on start... that's why I haven't posted any code.

Comment: But there IS some code, even though you haven't written it, that is failing. It probably came with the template you've downloaded, but it's broken anyway. Try to find that.

Comment: See edited post with code that was added from npx-create-next-app

Comment: My clean initializing of a NextJS project was rendering, unlike this situation, but had an 'Invalid hook call error.' **That** [had to do with an extension](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46601#issuecomment-1450075813).

Answer (score 0):

See the next.js Requirements (https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started) :

- Node.js 14.6.0 or newer (on your shell `node -v` return something like `v14.6.0` otherwise install node.js)
- MacOS, Windows (including WSL), and Linux are supported

And don't forget to do `npm init` before running it

Comment: I am using NodeJS 14.6.0 or newer, I am using Windows. You don't need to run npm init before starting a Next.JS app with npx create-next-app, I didn't do it before....